# CCTexture2D leaks of memory

Tags: memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

can anybody answer, i should change sprites image and i do it using my function

```
-(void) openKeyWithSprite:(id) sender withSpriteName:(NSString*)spriteName
```

can this lead to leaks of memory or it's ok?

in init

```
_spriteBonus=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monstr_1_1.png"];
```

in schedule

```
-(void) openKeyWithSprite:(id) sender withSpriteName:(NSString*)spriteName
{
        CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:spriteName];
        [_spriteBonus setTexture: tex];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shown here should be fine and won't leak any memory.  `setTexture` releases the old texture reference and retains the new one.

However, assuming you're not using ARC: `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monstr_1_1.png"];` is in the `autorelease` pool, so make sure you add it to a parent `CCNode` (before exiting whatever function you're creating it in) in order to keep it retained in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create frame animation, use CCAnimate action. For example,

```
id yourAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames: arrayOfFrames];
id animateAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration: animationDuration 
                                       animation: yourAnimation
                            restoreOriginalFrame: YES];
[yourSprite runAction: animateAction];
```

if you need to repeat your animation, use CCRepeat of CCRepeatForever action, for example

```
id resultAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: animateAction];
[yourSprite runAction: resultAction];
```

Comment: no, i post what i want. as I understand, alexander tries to create animated sprite. the way i offer much more easier and use the main cocos2d animation mechanism

Comment: no no... i'm just would like to change sprites image... static sprite, not animation and i do it, but whether this method lead to leaks of memory, in my case???